# Angular-Php-Python or Angular-Django, Python in PHP

Tags: python, php, django, angular

I have a graduation project. I made the frontend development with Angular. There is also a machine learning system I built using Python. I have to combine these two. So I planned to write a Web API for Angular using Django. But I haven't used Django before. And I approached the deadline.

I have created a Web API with PHP before and I am more experienced in PHP. I wonder what pros-cons would be if I developed this project as Angular->Php->Python? Should I learn Django quickly or do it with Php?

A second question is, if I am going to do it with Php, what should I do for Python and Php communication? Should I do it by running Python scripts through Php? Or should I write the result returned from Python to the file and get it from the file in Php? Using databes? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the project architecture...

An Angular frontend would communicate in HTTP with any backend web API your write. So this part is done.

For the web API/ML communication, it can be a lot of things. Maybe your ML side will store its result in a Database (or plain files, or anything), so the PHP API just have to read the results from the DB.

```
Python ML ---> Database <--- PHP backend <--- HTTP --- web browser
```

Or you have the ML part sending its results to your PHP backend on a private API. The PHP backend taking care of results storage.

```
            Database <--------
                             |
Python ML --- HTTP ---> PHP Backend <--- HTTP --- Web browser
                               |
     private network           |          public network
                               |
```

It all depends on the complexity your are ready to put in your project.
And of course, on the deadline you have.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Like the second one, I will have to send an HTTP request. Only database isn't sufficent. So is it possible/useful to control HTTP responses/requests without using any framework on the python side?

Comment: If the requests originate from the ML service, I suggest you check the "requests" library. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/